# Rounded corners on HTML List via css

Tags: html, css

I'm using a HTML list to display some content, but looking for a nicer solution. I'm really looking for rounded corners on the boxes.

Each item needs to be in container that has rounded corners -  not necessarily in a list.

```css
.list-type5 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
}

.list-type5 ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-type: decimal !ie;
  /*IE 7- hack*/
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: li-counter;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
}

.list-type5 ol li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #bfc4dc;
  padding-left: 58px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
}

.list-type5 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
}

.list-type5 li:hover {
  box-shadow: inset -1em 0 #8b9dc3;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

.list-type5 ol li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.3em;
  left: -0.5em;
  width: 1.8em;
  height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #8b9dc3;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  z-index: 99;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: counter(li-counter);
  counter-increment: li-counter;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>TEST 1</li>
  <li>TEST 2</li>
  <li>TEST 3</li>
</ol>
```

Need rounded corners on each item in the list. tried a few things but not sure if it's possible now, even using `<table>` - but did not look good on phone.

Comment: can you show us html

Comment: Please try this: `li{
display:block;
padding:.5em;
margin-bottom:.25em;
width:100px; 
border:1px solid; 
border-radius:5px;
}`

Comment: Have you tried [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)?

Comment: You're missing tag with `list-type5` class in your HTML, so your styles don't match any element in your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to use some of your code but not sure as you didn't provide html. Hope that'll help

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-type: decimal !ie; /*IE 7- hack*/
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: li-counter;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
}

ol li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #c6cfea;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  list-style-type: none;   
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

ol li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

ol li:hover
{
  box-shadow:inset -1em 0 #8b9dc3;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

ol li:nth-of-type(even):hover
{
  box-shadow:inset -1em 0 #aaa;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
  <li>List 4</li>
  <li>List 5</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add spans to the lis - to give the borders and border radius and use margin or padding on the li's to space them out?

If you want the items inline - then you can use display: inline-block on the li's and change hte styles accordingly.

```css
ul{
  padding-left: 0;
}

li{
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 16px 0;
  }

li span { 
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>TEST 1</span></li>
  <li><span>TEST 2</span></li>
  <li><span>TEST 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Task 1</li>
  <li>Task 2</li>
  <li>Task 3</li>
</ul>
```